# Type() not detecting my class (Tree) in Python 3

Tags: python, class, types

Came across something that I cannot understand properly.
Please have a look at the piece of code below.
This is a part of a program converting a binary tree to a list and record it as a file.
The problem I have is it fails to detect the Tree object and skips to the else: part of the if statement. 
I even put a print type(t) in the for loop before going into the if statement to check if it is a Tree object end it shows:

```
 <class '__main__.Tree'>
```

but Python still  skips the if clause (I also tried type(t) is Tree and type(t) == Tree, same result). There must be something I do not understand so if you can see it please let me know.

Variables at the first step after the program skips the damn if clause and goes into else for no reason I can grasp :) :

```
copy = {list} <class 'list'>: [<__main__.Tree object at 0x0000001EAAE549B0>]

t = {Tree} can it bark

cargo = {str} 'can it bark'




while len(bot_level) > 0:

        copy = bot_level[:]
        for t in copy:
            print(type(t))
            if isinstance(t, Tree):
                cargo_list.append(t.cargo)
                bot_level.append(t.left)
                bot_level.append(t.right)
                del bot_level[0]
            else:
                cargo_list.append(None)
                del bot_level[0]
```

Comment: If `print(type(t))` is not executed then maybe `copy`/`bot_level` is empty?

Comment: Sorry the print did not show because i did not indent it.

Comment: You should see it now.

Comment: Aren't you simply rebinding `Tree` somewhere inadvertently before using it here (noting that redeclaring `Tree` would be an example thereof)? Try `print(type(t), Tree)` instead and see if you get the same from both, and also `print(type(t) == Tree)`.

Comment: I shall check in the evening but considering that it prints type(t) in just before the if clause as: class __main__.'Tree' I don't think it has to do with rebinding...

Comment: Is this code  in `__main__`?

Comment: No its in a helper module. Hmm i shall check if it's a scope problem. Thx for a pointer.

Comment: Ok it is a scope problem. Hehe another thing I learnt :). Thx for your help.